# AttributeError: ‘numpy.ndarray’ object has no attribute ‘iloc’

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Why do the errors come up and how do I work around it?
If I take away '***.iloc***' another error comes up.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for tr_idx, val_idx in kf.split(X_train_new, y_train_new):

    clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(      
        n_estimators=500,
        max_depth=9,
        learning_rate=0.15,
        subsample=0.9,
        colsample_bytree=0.9,
        tree_method=’auto’
        )

    clf1 = lgb.LGBMClassifier(n_estimators=600,
        learning_rate=0.1,max_depth=9,
        boosting_type=’gbdt’,
        objective= ‘binary’,
        metric=’auc’,
        seed= 4,
        num_leaves= 7,
        n_jobs=-1)

    clf2 = GaussianNB()

    models = [clf, clf1, clf2]

    X_train_new, X_test_new = stacking(models,
        X_train_new, y_train_new,X_test_ch,
        regression=False,
        mode=’oof_pred_bag’,
        needs_proba=False,
        save_dir=None,
        metric=roc_auc_score,
        n_folds=3,
        stratified=True,
        shuffle=True,
        random_state=0,
        verbose=2
        )

    model = LogisticRegression()

    X_tr, X_vl = X_train_new.iloc[tr_idx, :], X_train_new.iloc[val_idx, :] 
    y_tr, y_vl = y_train_new.iloc[tr_idx], y_train_new.iloc[val_idx]

    model.fit(X_train_new, y_train_new)

    y_pred_train = model.predict_proba(X_vl)[:,1]
    y_oof[val_idx] = y_pred_train
    print(‘ROC AUC {}’.format(roc_auc_score(y_vl, y_pred_train)))
```

Comment: The error tells us that `X_train_new` is a numpy array.  `iloc` is a property of a pandas `DataFrame`.  At each point in your code you need to know what kind of objects you have, and what methods work with those objects.

Comment: Verified not empty
print(X_train_new.shape)
(591131, 49)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie didn't quite understand your answer

Comment: So this isn't your code. You didn't write it? Or if you did write it, what made you think you could use `iloc` here?  What is `X_train_new`?  How is it created?

Comment: My code, The error appeared after adding the ****Stacking****  function and I do not understand what the problem is

Comment: Without the ****stacking**** function, the code works

Comment: `stacking`? Where is that from? It's not numpy.  Your tags and imports don't show what other packages you are uaing.

Comment: from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score


EPOCHS = 3
kf = KFold(n_splits = EPOCHS, shuffle = True, random_state = RANDOM_SEED)
y_preds = np.zeros(sample_submission.shape[0])
y_oof = np.zeros(X_train_ch.shape[0])
X_train_new = X_train_ch[y_train == 0].sample(frac = 0.001).append(X_train_ch[y_train == 1])
y_train_new = y_train[X_train_new.index].reset_index().drop(columns = 'TransactionID')
X_train_new = X_train_new.reset_index().drop(columns = 'TransactionID')

Comment: Stacking is a function of a package    from vecstack import stacking

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that package.  What does its docs say?  What does it return?  pandas or numpy?

Comment: Depends on numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

Comment: https://github.com/vecxoz/vecstack/blob/master/vecstack/core.py says that `stacking` returns numpy arrays.  `stacking` does not require `pandas`.  Even if you pass it `DataFrames` it isn't going to return them!